# Does Android Studio has a memory analyzer tool like MAT in Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-memory

Eclipse has a powerful memory analyzer tool: MAT.

Does Android Studio have such a powerful tool, too ?

p.s.  I have found a "Allocation Tracking" in the Android DDMS page.
And I also know the "Memory Monitor".

But they seem very simple. Take "Memory Monitor" for example, it is only a wave graph. I don't even know which object are still connecting with the GC root.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Comment: Currenty, I think Android Studio has no built-in tool which could be compared to eclipse MAT. The features of "Memory Monitor" are very limited, IMHO. But you could use MAT as an external tool.

Comment: yes, my temporary way is to Use "MAT alone version" to analyze a .hprof file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to analyze memory using android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547555/how-to-analyze-memory-using-android-studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 1.3, they have integrated heap viewer in studio.

[Android studio 1.3 preview](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio13preview1available)

Comment: In 2.0 its in the Alt-6 Android Monitor-tab, under 'Memory|Cpu', 'Dump Java Heap' button on the left. Wait a while and a tab opens, where you can see currently allocated heap objects and references from code and sort by 'retained size'.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio 3.0 preview has much a much better tool, comparable to MAT, that also offers CPU and network activity profiling.

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/android-profiler.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes obviously!
Android Studio has very powerful tools for these purposes.

You can find these tools in the "Tools" tab.

Search for Tools > Android > Then you can explore "Memory Monitor" and "Android Device Monitor" as well.

Comment: "Memory Monitor" only shows a wave graph. I don't even know which object is still connecting with the GC root.

Comment: You can check detailed instruction from the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547555/how-to-analyze-memory-using-android-studio

Comment: You cannot compare the two... MAT is a ton more powerful!

Answer (score -2):

Try `Tools > Android > Memory Monitor` if you are looking for a high level overview.

Comment: "Memory Monitor" only shows a wave graph. I don't even know which object is still connecting with the GC root.