# Image adapter leaking memory

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter, picasso, okhttp

I have a simple *ListActivity* that shows images and I inizialize my *OkHttpClient* for *Picasso Builder* in the constructor of the ImageAdapter class:

```
picassoClient = new OkHttpClient();
picassoClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request newRequest = chain
            .request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Cookie","xyz")
            .build();

        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
});

new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(picassoClient)).build();
```

then in `getView()` I use Picasso to load images in ImageView:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(xyzUrl).fit().centerCrop().into(vImage);
```

It works well, but on device's rotation i see that **heap size** sometimes slowly grows, sometimes quickly and sometimes remains stable. Only rarely it drops. Am i leaking memory or is there something wrong in code?

**EDIT:**
I inserted this code after Picasso's call in the `getView()`

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Log.i("HEAP SIZE",
    String.valueOf((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024)
    - (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024)));
}
```

and I found that the heap size's growth happens in the `getView()` after loading bitmap into ImageView.
What is wrong?

**EDIT 2**: 
tried to set static ImageAdapter, nothing changes

**EDIT 3:**
tried with RecyclerView instead of ListView, same behavior: heap size grows continuously while scrolling image list stepping by 30-40 bytes at every `onBindViewHolder()`. After device's rotation heap size grows sometimes stepping by even 2-3 Mbytes. Rarely it drops.

Why heap size slowly but continuously grows and why am I leaking some cache or some cached bitmaps after device's rotation?

**UPDATE:**
tried adapter without the code in the constructor (that is without `new OkHttpClient` and `new Picasso.Builder`), it works and ***the heap size now drops well remaining stable***. Then, what is the correct way to initialize the client with cookies headers management?

**UPSHOT:**
finally I created my PicassoInstance class, which creates a unique static Picasso singleton and set it as the Picasso Library's singleton. Then I set it in my adapter constructor

`PicassoInstance.setPicassoSingleton(context);`

It works well, and it is a correct way I hope.

```
public class PicassoInstance {
private static Picasso myPicassoInstance = null;

public static void setPicassoSingleton(Context context) {
    if (myPicassoInstance == null) {
        myPicassoInstance = createMyPicassoInstance(context);
        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(myPicassoInstance);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.i("PICASSO INSTANCE", "CREATED");
        }
    }
}

private static Picasso createMyPicassoInstance(Context context) {
    OkHttpClient myOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    myOkHttpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Cookie", "xyz").build();
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.i("ON INTERCEPT", "COOKIE ADDED");
            }
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    });

    return new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(
            new OkHttpDownloader(myOkHttpClient)).build();
}
```

}

Comment: Please show your life cycle methods.

Comment: only `setListAdapter(adapter);` in `onCreate()`, nothing static, no other life cycle method.

Comment: So you are creating a new adapter each time in onCreate()?

Comment: yes: 
  `lv = getListView();
  adapter = new ImageAdapter(...)`

Comment: Then I'm guessing that the adapter is leaking something.  I you explicitly null it in onPause(), any change?  if not, might be worth showing your adapter code.  Do you bind it to anything else?

Comment: I edited my question,  I found that the heap size's growth happens in the getView().

Comment: Picasso caches images in memory for quick retrieval so my guess is it's just keeping references to the images until it feels the need to remove them.  I wouldn't worry about it until you produce a OOM error.

Comment: In fact it works well, however if I change the orientation dozens of times I get an OOM.

Comment: From picasso docs `Use with(android.content.Context) for the global singleton instance or construct your own instance with Picasso.Builder.`. So after you make the OkHttpClient, OkHttpDownloader and custom picasso instance...you throw it away. Or was that for illustration?

Comment: is this the same as [picasso-issue#968: PicassoDrawable's placeholder is not released if the drawable becomes another PicassoDrawable's placeholder.](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/968) ?

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec   I need to add cookie headers to get the images.

Comment: @k3b   i'm not using placeholder

Comment: I understand what you need to do, but you're not doing it. You construct the picasso instance and that's all. You don't store it, nobody uses it, it gets destroyed after the method ends. The images are loaded by `Picasso.with(context)` which is the default unmodified singleton instance. I suggest you create a `MyPicasso` singleton class for your custom picasso client.

Comment: tried to use `mPicasso=new Picasso.Builder(context)...` : on rotation heap size returns to grow.

Comment: The easiest way to track memory allocations is to use android's MAT utility. It gives a list of class objects that are not freed from the memory. You can read about its usage here: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Comment: fyi you only ever want 1 `OkHttpClient` so `private static OkHttpClient myClient;` then in method: `if(myClient == null) { myClient = new OkHttpClient()`  otherwise how else can it manage cache etc ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The picasso instance being returned from PicassoBuilder.build() should be a singleton, and when you need to use picasso throughout the app you should be accessing that singleton, instead of Picasso.with... you should be accessing

```
YourClass.getMyPicassoSingleton().with...
```

Otherwise you're keeping separate caches, etc for those picasso instances

edit: as I noted below, you can also call

```
picasso.setSingletonInstance(myPicasso);
```

right where you invoke the build method above, which would also solve your problem without holding onto the singleton yourself. that is probably a cleaner solution

Comment: i think under the hood picasso also does this and returns you a "singleton" each time anyway

Comment: https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java

if you invoke the builder yourself, it does not set its internal singleton. so if you invoke the builder method and build your own, and then go ahead and use Picasso.with later, you've created two instances. just look at the code it's very straightforward.

note that you can set the singleton on picasso with setsingletoninstance which would be an equally valid answer for OP and would solve the problem as well

Comment: glad you commented so i actually looked at the class and saw an easier solution haha

Comment: well, one question please: `Picasso.setSingletonInstance(myPicasso)` must be called once then how can I check this behavior after device's rotation,  must be my own instance _myPicasso_ static too?

Comment: i'm not clear what you mean. you only call setsingletoninstance once, like when you create the okhttp client. then on rotation you should just be using the picasso.with call and resetting the imageview. does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot close it as too broad, but I'd recommend you [took a memory dump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24547957/1266326) and gave it a long hard look in [Eclipse Memory Analizer Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php) to find which references are still being kept alive and by who.

This is also [a great write up on it](http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/04/hunting-your-leaks-memory-management-in-android-part-2-of-2/).

Adapters as fields are leaky. Views contain context which contains views. And fragments are even worse offenders. ListActivities were an API1 tool that should have been deprecated long ago. All very leak prone, but that's the Android way.