# How do you debug an Android app that crashes the device?

Tags: android, crash, device, android-videoview

I'm currently having an issue with certain Samsung devices where starting an activity with an intro animation sometimes causes the whole device to crash.

The app essentially transitions from an Activity with a VideoView to another activity with a VideoView. The video of the activity that just started stutters in a loop for about 10 seconds before the whole device crashes and restarts.

It's not crashing the device all the time, but is limited to a couple Samsung devices from what I've tested.

I've looked at crash logs of the device which currently seem to be inconclusive from what I can see.

Important but relevant note, I am finishing the activity once starting the next.

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak in Samsung's ROM. This is a common practice on Samsungs since most roms are copy pasted

Comment: If your source code is short. You can try debug step by line. Or you can check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547555/how-to-analyze-memory-using-android-studio then you can see some tool checking memory or time of app. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to attach the debugger manually through Android Studio if your process is alive long enough after the boot sequence.

Source: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

One more thing you could try is to put the 'wait for debugger' instruction in your code, using the `Debug.waitForDebugger()` method.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#waitForDebugger()

Other than that, you could put a lot of logs in your code, then fetch them using `adb logcat > crash-log.txt` command from your CMD/Terminal.