# How to download and view hprof file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

The latest android studio has the built in memory analyzer  as per the release notes:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/07/get-your-hands-on-android-studio-13.html

I am not able to find the option in the menu or through the  search option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to analyze memory using android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547555/how-to-analyze-memory-using-android-studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Android bottom tab >> Memory >> Dump Java Heap*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are using **Android Studio 1.3** you can do it. I will give you the tutorial.

**Step 1**

Start your app on either a real devices connected or on an emulator

**Step 2**

Click on the **Android** tab to view the Free and Allocated memory in the Memory Analyzer

**Step 3**

Click on the **Java Heap** icon on the left hand side on the left. This will create a heap snapshot file for you in the format `Snapshot-yyyy.mm.dd-hh.mm.ss.hprof`

**Step 4**

Just double-click on the snapshot file to view it in the HPROF viewer.

Comment: Did this help you somehow? Or there is something more I can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

create folder `captures`in root folder of project and past .hprof and open using Android Studio -> Captures and Enjoy debugging