# Lots of memory allocated with an only framelayout

Tags: java, android, performance, memory-management

When I open this activity the memory allocated goes from 11MB to almost 50MB..

In this activity I've only a framelayout with Images.. And I move the dot image with the onTouchEvent..

Can Anyone tell me why I'm using such a lot memory? Even when I press the back button leaving the activity the memory allocated remains 50MB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fl"
    tools:context="it.uniroma3.sensorlog">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@mipmap/mappa"
    android:id="@+id/map"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
    android:id="@+id/dot"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The point is: we can't know.

Thing is: this memory is somehow consumed by **your** application. Which only *you* are able to run and profile.

Thus, the essential answer here is: learn how to use the corresponding tools; and go figure yourself.

Good starting points would be [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html), or that other existing[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547555/how-to-analyze-memory-using-android-studio) on that subject.

Given your comment; and the other answer: a first, direct experiment could be: go for a very small set of small images; and see if that makes a difference. If it does; you know *where* to search.

Comment: I know, but it's a really simple application.. two activities:
1) in the first one there's only a textview
2) in the second one there are only these two imageviews.. the map view is full screen and the second one is just a dot image

Comment: Why does this have a downvote? It's true, we can't know why your application consumes a lot of memory by looking at ONE xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem is most probably with your image resolution, try reducing it.